# Uploading Data to an Existing List in Batch Process

Tags: custom-list, batch

I have 252 items to add to an existing list and wanted to paste in batch of 20 but SP 2013 complains about the format of my data which I thought was correct (e.g Text in text columns, dates in date columns) Is there a way round this? I don't want to add them separately.

Comment: Check the date format of your data and list's date column format

Comment: can you provide some more information about approach.. you trying same with CSOM or Server Object Model.
Code snippet would also be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to copy into a list from excel?